# please state the theorem about identity theorem, detailly

Tags: complex-analysis

In today's class, I learned the following theorem:

Let $f$ be analytic on domain $\mathbb{D}$, and {$z_n$} be a sequence of distinct numbers which approaches $z_0$ as $n \to \infty$. Suppose that $f(z_n)=0$ for each $n \geq 1$. Then the function $f$ is identically equal to $0$.

My question is about the mentioned sequence {$z_n$}. Do the conditions of the theorem have to hold for *all* sequences $z_n \to z_0$, or does there only have to exists *some* sequence $z_n \to z_0$. I predict that "*all* sequences" is probably correct.

If you know that the precise meaning of the theorem, please state it in detail.

Comment: If there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}$ such that..., then $f(z)$ is identically $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be analytic function on domain D.

> Identitytheorem
>   Suppose "there exist point $z_0$ in D and sequence $z_n$ in D" such that $z_n$ converges to $z_0$ satisfying $f(z_n)=0$ for all $n$.
>   If  "for infintely many $n$" $z_n$ is not $z_0$ , then $f(z)=0$ in D.

For all sequence $z_n$ converging $z_0$ Is very strong condition.

Comment: I have a small doubt related to the identity theorem If f(z) is analytic in the unit disc D and there exists some sequence in disc D whose even terms go to zero and odd terms go to infinity such that f(z_n)=0 then also can we say identity theorem conditions are satisfied and f(z)=0 for all z in D?

Comment: Please reply thank you

Answer (score 0):

The identity theorem only requires **one** such sequence to exist. If there exists any convergent sequence in $\Bbb D$ (with its limit point also in $\Bbb D$) such that $f$ is zero on the sequence, then $f$ is zero everywhere in $\Bbb D$.

If the statement were "all" sequences, then the theorem would be near-trivial. If the condition were satisfied, then all sequences $\{ z_n \}$ have the property that $f(z_i) = 0$. But for each $w \in \Bbb D$, there's a sequence containing $w$. And so $f(w) = 0$ anyways.